# How to pass parameters to a hql run via airflow

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I would like to know how I can pass a parameter to an hive query script run via airflow. If I want to add a parameter only for this script say target_db = mydatabase, how can i do that? Do I need to add it to the default_args and then call it in then call it in the op_kwargs of the script?

```
default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': True,
    'start_date': datetime(2017, 11, 1),
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 2,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
}

dag = DAG(dag_name, default_args=default_args, schedule_interval="@daily")

t_add_step = PythonOperator(
    task_id='add__step',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=add_emr_step,
    op_kwargs={
        'aws_conn_id': dag_params['aws_conn_id'],
        'create_job_flow_task': 'create_emr_flow',
        'get_step_task': 'get_email_step'
    },
    dag=dag
)
```

Comment: Hive command line provides an option `--database` that you could use when you are invoking Hive

Comment: For global `Hive` cli options, one might also use [`hive_cli_params` field](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/hooks/hive_hooks.py#L58) in [`extra` dict](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/models.py#L665) of `Airflow` `Connection` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are invoking Hive using BashOperator, it would look something like this

```
...
set_hive_db = BashOperator (
    bash_command = """
     hive --database {{params.database}} -f {{params.hql_file}}
     """,
     params = {
       "database": "testingdb",
       "hql_file": "myhql.hql"
     },
     dag = dag
)
...
```

Another approach would be to `USE database` inside your hql and just call `hive -f hqlfile.hql` in your BashOperator